# Robocopy Error 3 "System cannot find the file specified" for 1 file in the folder

Tags: robocopy

I am  trying to copy a folder from the network path to my machine .But while copying the folder the robocopy suddenly got stuck in copying 1 file from the folder and did not proceed forward . I am seeing the error ERROR 3 (0x00000003) , "The System cannot find the path specified." , even though the file did exist in the source directory.
The command that I use is 
     ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR /Z /Log+:logs.txt
I am seeing this issue when my executable is triggered by the task scheduler. This issue does not happen when i run the exe directly. Any idea why this could be happening and also how to fix this problem

Answer (score 5):

When robocopy claims it cannot find a file, it often means it is running into permission issues. If your script works from the command line, but not from the task scheduler, make sure the task uses your user credentials. You can set them in the task properties on the general tab under security options.